# Our MySQL is read heavy, but iostat reports that almost no reads are taking place. How come?

Tags: mysql, raid, iostat

According to MySQL's `STATUS` command, we have about 500 reads and ~20 writes to our DB per second.

But `iostat` is reporting that ~70 writes (`w/s`) and ~0.5 reads (`r/s`) are taking place on the corresponding device.

Why isn't `iostat` showing all the activity that should be caused by the `SELECT`s? Does this mean that they are hitting some cache and that's why we are not seeing them? If this is the case, how can I tell?

(The filesystem the DB is on is a BBU Raid 10 with SSD discs.)

Comment: It seems that `iostat` only reports data that hits the device, and not data that was in   the page cache. This could explain the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: That would be my guess.  Either the DB's internal buffers keep it all in memory, or the file cache is doing it.